# How to use the API to get the top 20 streams

Tags: python, json, api, twitch

I am trying to write a Python script to get the top 20 streams using the API. However, I could not find a guide online. I am going off of the python-twitch-client [docs](https://python-twitch-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/v5/streams.html) but so far I couldn’t find something helpful. I’ll admit, its my first time ever working with this API.

Precisely, this is what I want to accomplish: https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference#get-streams I know that the default return is 20 streams.

At the moment, this is all the code I have:

```
from twitch import TwitchClient
client = TwitchClient(client_id='<my client id>')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to working with APIs - it is definitely a blast.

In this scenario, assuming you've successfully created your application and [retrieved your client id as outlined in the instructions](https://python-twitch-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#authentication), to get the latest streams you would use [`get_live_streams`](https://python-twitch-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/v5/streams.html#twitch.api.streams.Streams.get_stream_by_user)

```
from twitch import TwitchClient

client = TwitchClient(client_id='<client-id>')
streams = client.streams.get_live_streams()

print(streams)
```

The API provides other functions you can use to retrieve other data such as `get_featured`, `get_stream_by_user`, and more. You can view all those [functions in the documentation](https://python-twitch-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/v5/streams.html).

Comment: This works in colab but not on an IDE.  I'm using PyCharm.

Comment: Also, how can I find the username through this?